# Diophantine equation implementation

Tags: python

I've been asked to do the following: 
If it is possible to buy x, x+1,…, x+5 sets of McNuggets, for some x, then it is possible to buy any number of McNuggets >= x, given that McNuggets come in 6, 9 and 20 packs. Write an iterative program that finds the largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity.

Here's the code i came up with, but it get's stuck in an infinite loop:

```
count = 0
n = 1
while count < 6:
    six_consequtive = True
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            for c in range(n):
                if 6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n:
                    six_consequtive = False
    if six_consequtive:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0

    n += 1

print("Largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity: %d." % (n - 5))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the "six consecutive" test?  Did your homework assignment say that once you find six values with some property in a row, that you could assume you have the answer?  If so, could you describe that property?

Comment: Yes, as i stated in the question abouve, if it is possible to buy x, x+1,…, x+5 sets of McNuggets, for some x, then it is possible to buy any number of McNuggets >= x, given that McNuggets come in 6, 9 and 20 packs. It's because if you find 6 consequtive sets, you can always add 6 to each set of them infinitely. Therefore, the set that was before set x is the biggest set that can't be bought. 
I hope i understood you question correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear what the problem is: you only increment `count` when it is possible to get the exact quantity.  Any time you don't increment `count` you reset it to 0, and the loop only stops when this exceeds 6.  That might take a while.

You wrote a triply-nested `for` loop, so the larger `n` gets, the slower these loops get.  It's possible that if you let it run long enough it might succeed and finish someday; but your basic algorithm is just too slow.

You can find out more by instrumenting your loops with print statements.  When I tried it, I wasn't getting output; I figured that was probably due to buffering issues, so I wrote a simple output function that outputs a string and then flushes to make sure I can see the output right away.

Here's your program so edited:

```
import sys

def out(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s + "\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()

count = 0
n = 1
while count < 6:

    six_consecutive = True
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            for c in range(n):
                #out("a: %d b: %d c: %d  n: %d" % (a, b, c, n))
                if 6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n:
                    six_consecutive = False

    out("n == %d  count == %d  six_consecutive == %s" %
            (n, count, str(six_consecutive)))

    if six_consecutive:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0

    n += 1

print("Largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity: %d." % (n - 5))
```

I also fixed the spelling on "six_consecutive".

So, how should you fix this?  I think you should throw this away and rewrite with a better algorithm.  You might want to check and see how other people have solved this problem, or a similar problem.  This strikes me as being very similar to the classic problem of how to make change, when given a set of coins of different denominations.

NOTE: The classic problem of making change usually assumes a sensible set of coins, including a coin with the value 1.  A simple "greedy" algorithm, starting with the largest coin and working down, will always succeed.  This is a bit more interesting because the "coins" set is weird and there are values that cannot be found, so maybe the classic coin problem isn't as relevant as I thought.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But i finally got my algorithm working, and i don't thing i just had to change the boolean values in the six_consequtive and -5 to -7 in the print statement.

Comment: Do you mean that the McNuggets come in quantities of 5, 7, and 20?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry , i just realized i had the boolean values reversed. The first six_consequtive at the beginning of the loop should be assigned False and the second True.
Again, I'm very sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: When you make this change and run the program, it gets the answer 45.  If you buy 5 boxes of the 9-count McNuggets, 5 * 9 == 45, so this is not a correct answer.

Comment: If you feel the question is not useful you can delete it.

Comment: You are right, i also had to change the -5 to -7. I think the -5 was a typo :D .